# PostgreSQL / PostGraphile row permissions not working

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgraphql

I'm trying to set up a GraphQL server with PostGraphile (formerly known as PostGraphQL) and I cannot get the row permissions working, meaning that I keep getting permission denied messages, despite it should work. Here is my schema:

```
create function app.current_user() returns app.profile as $$
  select *
  from app.profile
  where id = current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id')::integer
$$ language sql stable;

comment on function app.current_user() is 'Gets the person who was identified by our JWT.';

grant select (name,about,created_at,updated_at) on table app.profile to app_user;
grant update (name,about) on table app.profile to app_user;
alter table app.profile enable row level security;


create policy select_profile on app.profile for select to app_user
  using (id = current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id')::integer);

create policy update_profile on app.profile for update to app_user
  using (id = current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id')::integer);
```

as far as I can see in debug output, everything works as it should. I can authenticate, get a JWT token, it complains with a proper error message when the JWT token is invalid, so it's not any of that.

what am I doing wrong, or how can I debug more closely what is happening?

I'm using PostGraphile v4 and PostgreSQL 10.4

Comment: Could you be more specific about what's not working? Is it allowing you to update other people's data? (That would imply you're connecting to the database as a superuser or database owner, perhaps, which bypasses RLS.) Is it not allowing you to view any data at all? (That would imply that the jwt.claims.person_id is incorrect; *or* that you're not setting the role to `app_user` via the JWT, or that the JWT role path setting is correct.) Perhaps you could share your signed JWT and the `postgraphile` command line you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue myself. It turns out that you **must** give permissions on the id, even if you don't select it but only use it in the WHERE part.

So in the above example, modify it to:

> grant select (id,name,about,created_at,updated_at) on table app.profile to app_user;

then it should work.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further? How do you give permissions on the id?